# Integrations tests with Angular and J2EE

Tags: angularjs, maven, integration-testing

I have two projects. One of them is an angular project created by [yeoman scaffoding](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular). The other one is a J2EE maven archetype.

Both project are independent and are placed in diferent repositories.

I have to make an integration test. 
How can I do to make integration tests?

Comment: are you using some task runner like grunt or gulp?

Comment: Yes, it's a yeoman project, I use grunt.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917207/integration-testing-frameworks-for-testing-a-distributed-system

Comment: keep the javaEE application started, and run the integration tests in the angular project. Where are you having problems?

Comment: I have problems for example with fixtures if I run test in angular.